# Get all the defined mappings from an AutoMapper defined mapping

Tags: c#, dictionary, expression, automapper

Let's assume that I've two classes : CD and CDModel, and the mapping is defined as follows:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<CDModel, CD>()
        .ForMember(c => c.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Title));
```

Is there an easy way to retrieve the original **expression** like *c => c.Name* (for source) and *m => m.Title* (for destination) from the mapping?

I tried this, but I miss some things...

```cs
var map = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor<CDModel, CD>();
foreach (var propertMap in map.GetPropertyMaps())
{
    var source = ???;
    var dest = propertMap.DestinationProperty.MemberInfo;
}
```

How to get the source and destination expressions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Going along the same path as what you were doing ...

```
foreach( var propertMap in map.GetPropertyMaps() )
{
    var dest = propertMap.DestinationProperty.MemberInfo;
    var source = propertMap.SourceMember;
}
```

How exactly do you want the expressions? Are you wanting the underlying Lambas?

If so look at

```
propertMap.GetSourceValueResolvers()
```

Answer (score 2):

I also find `var map = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps();` to be useful too, as you can search for the **SourceType** or **DestinationType**.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Automapper 7.0 and the syntax is different now.  For example,

```
void Dump(TypeMap map)
{
    Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine(map.SourceType + " ==> " + map.DestinationType);
    foreach (var m in map.GetPropertyMaps())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.SourceMember.Name + " ==> " + m.DestinationProperty.Name);
    }
}
```

And then you can call it using:

```
Dump(Mapper.Instance.ConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor(typeof(CDModel), typeof(CD)));
```

or if you want to dump out everything, then do like this.

```
foreach (var map in Mapper.Instance.ConfigurationProvider.GetAllTypeMaps())
{
    Dump(map);
}
```

Comment: equivalent for `var m in map.GetPropertyMaps()` in AutoMapper 8?

Comment: For my solution which covers AutoMapper 7 and 8, see https://github.com/StefH/FluentValidation.Extensions.AutoMapper/blob/master/src/FluentValidation.Extensions/FluentValidationPropertyNameResolver.cs